# Remove RecyclerView Item from Dialog not updating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a simple RecyclerView for displaying items. Currently, from the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, I can delete items successfully using the following.

```
private void removeItem(int pos) {    
    filteredDataSet.remove(pos);
    notifyItemRemoved(pos);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, getItemCount());
}
```

I call it from the `onClick()` function in the `ViewHolder`.The animations work, the view is updated, everything works. Pretty standard RecyclerView.

However, what I'd like to do is have the user verify the item deletion via a `Dialog`. Here's the basic setup for the Dialog (leaving out unnecessary code):

```
...

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
builder.setTitle("Delete this item?");
builder.setView(layout);

final int itemPos = pos;

builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        removeItem(itemPos);
    }
}); 

...
```

So, I'm just moving the method call into the `onClickListener` of the Dialog.

The problem I'm having is that when the RecyclerView animates away the removed item, it animates it back in the exact same position, and the list stays the same. Like it's still there.

But, if I scroll down I get a out of bounds error:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position`

Which means it's not actually there, and when go back and come into the View again, it's gone. So, it seems like it's cached and not updating the adapter or dataset. I read that it needs called on the main thread, so I modified my method to this:

```
private void removeItem(int pos) {
final int itemPos = pos;

Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        filteredDataSet.remove(itemPos);
        notifyItemRemoved(itemPos);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(itemPos, getItemCount());
    }
};
handler.post(runnable);
}
```

It's still not working, and I'm at a loss. I suspect it's a thread issue, but not sure where to turn from here.

Comment: try to dubug. code is correct to remove position from list.
I think problem is onclick event of yes button from where you are calling removeItem method, Here just check whether you are passing correct item position?

Comment: what is filteredDataSet ? does it have any values ?

Comment: @keyur9779: the position being passed is correct. @quick learner: filteredDataSet is a `List<>` which is populated via a SQL database. It's functioning as desired (minus the problem mentioned, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was solved by using a callback to trigger the `removeItem()` function when the item is deleted from the database. Apparently, adapter was being notified before the item was actually deleted from the database.

I'm using DBFlow to perform queries, so the solution is only applicable to DBFlow based solutions. This is called from the view that holds the RecyclerView:

```
public void deleteItem(int pos, long id) {
    DatabaseDefinition database = FlowManager.getDatabase(AppDatabase.class);

    //hold id to remove later
    final long tempId = id;
    final int tempPos = pos;

    final ItemModel currentItem = getItem(id);

    Transaction transaction = database.beginTransactionAsync(new ITransaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(DatabaseWrapper databaseWrapper) {
            currentItem.delete();
        }
    }).success(new Transaction.Success() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Transaction transaction) {
            mAdapter.removeItem(tempPos); //called here
        }
    }).error(new Transaction.Error() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Transaction transaction, Throwable error) {
            Log.d("delete error", "item not deleted");
        }
    }).build();

    transaction.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your removing from `onClick` from `ViewHolder` class then use `getAdapterPosition()` to get clicked location

if this code not working can you tell what is `onItemClick()` from your `ViewHolder`

Comment: Sorry, `onItemClick` is an interface method that is originally called by `onClick`. The adapter position is being set in `onBindViewHolder(holder,position)` via the position argument. After a little research this morning, I suspect that I may need to use `getAdapterPostition()`, as you suggested, for click events.

Comment: @anthony does my solution is helped

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. Whether I set the position via the second argument in `onBindViewHolder` or use `getAdapterPosition()`, it makes no difference. Both return the correct position. This seems like a bug, or as I hypothesized earlier, a threading issue. The only thing that changes is the introduction of a `Dialog`. Otherwise, the code works perfect.